# Authorization header stored as part of environment

Tags: paw-app

Is it possible to store the Authorization header or feed the header as part of an environment? I keep various server URLs in my environment but the Auth header needs to change as part of that as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitively possible. Here's a doc article about it:
https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Environments_as_Reusable_Presets